# Ruby Mechanize - can't get specific selectlist

Tags: ruby, forms, mechanize

I know this is working on other form/selectlist I've tried.  This particular one doesn't appear to be ajax.  Can anyone shed light on this?

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'open-uri'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://espn.go.com/nba/team/transactions/_/name/bos/boston-celtics')

form = page.form_with(:class => "js-goto")
fields = form.field_with(:class => "tablesm")

puts fields
```

It should be returning something like `#<Mechanize::Form::SelectList:0x007ffdd3930138>`

Comment: Just to confirm, you're trying to change the year?

Comment: I'm trying to navigate the page by year, but its not even registering the selectlist.  Thats pretty much where I isolated the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That selectlist doesn't have a name attribute, which makes it useless as a form field.
You can still get the data you need to navigate nokogiri style:

```
page.at('select.tablesm option[text()="2008"]')[:value]
#=> "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/transactions/_/name/bos/year/2008/boston-celtics"
```

Comment: ok so if the form field doesn't have a `name` attribute, then no mechanize

Comment: Mechanize uses nokogiri, so you can use the above on the page object generated by mechanize.

Comment: You can still use Mechanize, but not Mechanize::Form. The form never gets submitted, an onchange javascript event gets fires instead, so you can't treat that one like a form.

Comment: Followup question.  How do you trigger a click on an option?

Comment: You get the url from the option's value the way I showed you, and then you `agent.get` that url.